# Sharepoint 2007 - Adding a column to the "All Documents' view so it appears in all document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-2007, document-library

I was wondering if it was possible to modify the default document library view "All Documents " to include the "Checked Out To" column.

I need this change to apply to any existing document libraries as well as any created in the future.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to change the OOTB features in SharePoint. I would make a new feature that contains the column in the default view. Just copy DocumentLibrary feature and make the proper adjustments and just use that one in the future for new document libraries.

To handle the already existing libraries I would write a bit of code (C#/PS) to add the column to the default view.